# Finding files and directories with different umask

Tags: bash, shell, find, chmod

ihave an umask 0002 using `umask -S` it returns `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx.`

How do i find all files and directories that does now have rights set up accordin to mask?

The directories goes `777 - mask` and files `666 - mask` If i do something like

```
find . ! -perm $(umask -S)
```

it will find all files/directories that does not have rights set to u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx ( 777 - 002 are there rights but 666 - 002 are differnt rights) which is good for directories , but not for files.

How do i find files , that have different rights than current set umask?

example

```
 touch one
 ls -l
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 trolkura trolkura 0 kvě  4 09:01 one
```

umask is 0002 so this results in 664 , but when i do

```
find . -type f ! -perm $(umask -S)
./one
```

result is the newly created file bcs it is looking for files that does not have 775 rights (Directory rights)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```bash
m=`umask`
fperm=`printf '0%o' $(( 0666 & ~$m ))`
dperm=`printf '0%o' $(( 0777 & ~$m ))`

find -type f -perm $fperm -o -type d -perm $dperm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f ! -perm $(echo "obase=8;$(( 8#666 ^ 8#$(umask) ))"|bc)
```

That's a binary xor operation on octal numbers. The decimal result is converted to octal again since `-perm` accepts octal permissions.

Comment: this result in 436 not 664 as it should

Comment: @trolkura update done, forgotten to reconvert decimal result.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case solution would be to set cases depending on `umask`...

If your umask `u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx` is the you can find files that have the evil 666 like this:

```
 find . -type f ! -perm u=rw,g=rw,o=r
```

If your umask `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`, then you use another string ...

```
 find . -type f ! -perm u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

... not proud of that one.